# SQL INSERT INTO VALUES

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have 2 tables :

TableUser

| UserID | Name | FirstName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CAMERON | James |
| 2 | CONNOR | John |
| 3 | CONNOR | Sarah |

TableTarget

| UserID | TargetName | TargetLocation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Someone... | Someplace... |
| 2 | Someone... | Someplace... |
| 4 | Someone... | Someplace... |
| 3 | Someone... | Someplace... |
| 2 | Someone... | Someplace... |

And I have a CSV file to fulfil my TargetTable. I thought it would be easy by formating my CSV to make a SQL command like

```
INSERT INTO
TableTarget (UserID,TargetName,TargetLocation)
VALUES
(2,'Someone...','Someplace...'),
(2,'Someone...','Someplace...'),
(3,'Someone...','Someplace...')
```

But I don't have the UserID in my CSV file, I have the Name and FirstName:

```
Name;FirstName;TargetName;TargetLocation
```

And I don't know how to do. Worst, among my hundred users, sometimes they have the same Name.
I would be glad to have some help!
Thanks!

Comment: You need a field or group of fields in your csv file that let you find univocally a user in your database's table. Names and last names are not good fields to find univocally someone, because they could be misspell. You could try to look for by phonetic names and last names, and if you find only one user, you could assume this is the user you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the CSV table into a staging table.  Then load the final result using a `join`:

```
insert into targettable (UserID, UserID TargetName  TargetLocation, TargetLocation)
    select u.userid, tts.TargetName, tts.TargetLocation
    from targettable_staging tts join
         tableuser u
         on u.name = tts.name and u.firstname = tts.firstname;
```

You might want another step where you load unknown users into the user table.  And the whole time you'll keep your fingers crossed that users have unique names.

Comment: Thanks, I will use another table to make then a join.